# (Unity) Can onClick.Addlistener casue Memory Leak?

Tags: unity-game-engine, event-handling

I found a code that is suspected of being a memory leak
and I wonder if this really causes a memory leak.

The code below is a summary.
It's different from the actual code,
but the behavior is pretty much the same.

```
void Update()
{
    button.onClick.Addlistener(() =>
    {
        Debug.log("Clicked!!");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's kinda obvious that it is. The code you provided generates a new lambda in every update call and adds it as a listener. And this is not an `onClick.AddListener` issue.

Comment: can you imagine like 10 mins in clicking whatever button that is and like the 20k runs of it....

Answer (score 1):

`Update()` is called every frame so this code is adding the listener to the button every frame!

This means that, in a program running at a normal 60 frames per second, after only 1 minute has passed you will have added the same listener 3600 times!

So if you click that button after 1 minute, you will call `Debug.log("Clicked!!");` 3600 times.

While this alone may not cause a memory leak, running code that creates objects in RAM would most definitely cause memory issues.

Whichever way you look at it, you should NEVER add listeners in any update loop.

`Start()` or `OnEnable()` are good places to do this depending on your needs.
This will add the listener once as it should be done.

Furthermore, you should remove the listener if you don't need it anymore or if the listener would be duplicated otherwise.

So if you added the listener in `Start()` then `OnDestroy()` is probably where you would want to remove it.
If you used `OnEnable()` then you should probably do so in `OnDisable()`.

And this all goes for any event subscription!